# Regex - How to parse body email

Tags: regex, email, parsing

I need to extract all the data information from body email with regex (so to obtain in output columns "Notification Type", "Service", "Host", "Address", "State", "Date/Time", "Additional Info").
The body of email is like the following:

```
Notification Type: AAAAAA

Service: Percentile: Interface vlanxxxx
Host: Oslo.group.xxx
Address: 99.200.XX.YYY
State: OK

Date/Time: Sun Sept 10 22:53:32 CEST 2017

Additional Info:

OK - Interface 400 = Average IN: 140.626Gbps(50.50%), Average OUT: 519.888Mbps(80.962%)
```

Please can anyone help me?
Regards

Comment: Have you even tried anything? `^[^:]*:\s*(.+$)`?

Comment: Is Percentile part of Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/icFMF3/2)

```
^[^:]*:\s*(.+)
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Notification Type: AAAAAA

Service: Percentile: Interface vlanxxxx
Host: Oslo.group.xxx
Address: 99.200.XX.YYY
State: OK

Date/Time: Sun Sept 10 22:53:32 CEST 2017

Additional Info:

OK - Interface 400 = Average IN: 140.626Gbps(50.50%), Average OUT: 519.888Mbps(80.962%)
```

#### Output

Below results are contents of capture group 1

```
AAAAAA
Percentile: Interface vlanxxxx
Oslo.group.xxx
99.200.XX.YYY
OK
Sun Sept 10 22:53:32 CEST 2017
OK - Interface 400 = Average IN: 140.626Gbps(50.50%), Average OUT: 519.888Mbps(80.962%)
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[^:]*` Match any character except `:` any number of times
- `:` Match this literally
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `(.+)` Capture one or more of any character into capture group 1

Comment: Hello ctwheels, good code! However I need one regex for every field in a mail....have you any suggestion for me?

Comment: Do you want to capture the fields in a group (such that your return is an array similar to `Notification Type`, `AAAAAA`) or do you want to select each group according to a regex (such that you only get an array of values like I have above, but you use multiple regular expressions `^Notification Type:\s*(.+)`)?

Comment: I want to select each group according to a regex

Comment: I choise the option2.

Comment: @Ema may I ask which programming language you are using? A more simple answer may be available depending on your language

Comment: I'm using Pentaho Spoon

Comment: @Ema In that case, I'd suggest using something like what was proposed by jiwopene, but prepend each regex with `^` and enable `multiline` mode. Also, instead of hardcoding the space after `:` as jiwopene has done, replace with with `\s*` such that each regex resembles the format: `^Notification Type:\s*(.+)`

Comment: Thanks a lot ctwheels for your support!

Answer (score 0):

### Notification type

```
^Notification Type: (.*)$
```

### Service

```
^Service: (.*)$
```

### Host

```
^Host: (.*)$
```

### Address

```
^Address: (.*)$
```

### State

```
^State: (.*)$
```

### Date/Time

```
^Date/Time: (.*)$
```

---

The last line is the line where is no regex accepted. Everywhere is assumed the `m` (**m**ultiline) flag. If you do not want to use it, replace `$` character with `[\r\n]`.

The `^` character matches beginning of the line.

Comment: What do you mean by `The last line is simply the line where is no regex accepted.`? What if the `Additional Info` contained `External-Host: Something here`, you'll catch that.

Comment: Thanks a lot jiwopene!

Comment: @ctwheels Add a `^` character to the start of regulal expressions. It matches start of the line.

Comment: @jiwopene see the comments below my question. If you change it to the format I specify, you'll be providing the OP with the correct answer for their problem.